# Encryption of dataConfig section fields in SOLR

Tags: solr

Im generating SOLR from DB with below dataConfig section in data-config.xml file, and it's working fine.

```
<dataConfig> 
 <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"  driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"  
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;databaseName=emp" user="user" password="user"/> 
    <document name="reviews"> 
       <entity name="COMMON" query="select id,name from users" > 
           <field column="id" name="id"/> 
           <field column="name" name="name"/>
      </entity> 
    </document> 
</dataConfig>
```

I want to ENCRYPT the url, databaseName, user and password fields in above configuration.

Please Help,

Thanks in Advance.

AnilJayanti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can parameterize the pwd field (or any other field). Like here below, I have parameterized the password field:

```
<dataConfig>
     <dataSource name="jdbc" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//testdbserver:1521/db1" user="tester"  password="${dataimporter.request.pwd}"/>
</dataConfig>
```

So when you call the server, you can pass the pwd as a parameter:

http://www.googleserver:/solr/dataimport?command=full-import&pwd=sa

Now, you would probably have to encrypt the password or user in the url above (using DES) - and then find a way to decrypt on the SolR side. For decryption on the SolR side, you would have to write a custom evaluator (though it is possible that SolR provides a function to decrypt that I could not find).

Alternately, the parameter can be taken from a custom evaluator. See the link below for understanding custom evaluators:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Custom_Evalutaors

So, for example:

```
<dataConfig>
    <function name="getPwd" class="myFoo.FetchPwd"/>
    <dataSource name="jdbc" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//testdbserver:1521/db1" user="tester"  password="${dataimporter.functions.getPwdFromAsc}"/>
</dataConfig>
```