# Solr config, encrypting data config file

Tags: encryption, solr, indexing

How can I encrypt the data config portion here?:

```
<dataConfig> 
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"  driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"  
url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;databaseName=emp" user="user" password="user"/> 
<document name="reviews"> 
   <entity name="COMMON" query="select id,name from users" > 
       <field column="id" name="id"/> 
       <field column="name" name="name"/>
  </entity> 
</document> 
</dataConfig>
```

Basically, I don't want to expose the user and password.

Alternately, if data config files cannot be encrypted (partly or completely), can I do indexing of a database using SolrJ such that I do not have to configure a data config file? That is, I pass the url and authentication parameters using SolrJ apis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more secure option, I would suggest is to configure a **JNDI** in your webserver.

How to configure a JNDI? [This Page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example) explains how to do so with Tomcat. It can be done for other popular webservers as well.

You can use the JNDI name in your data config file as follows:

```
< dataSource name="xyz" jndiName="jdbc/xyz" type="JdbcDataSource"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure that Solr DataImportHandler supports jndiName attribute? I cannot see it in [the list](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Configuring_JdbcDataSource).

Comment: I don't see it in this list either. The impression that I am getting is that I have to do one of the following: 1. Plug in a datasource through a class as defined here: [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#datasource) 2. Parameterize as I have mentioned here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745073/encryption-of-dataconfig-section-fields-in-solr/15123453#15123453) 3. use properties (see below) but how does that solve the problem that I cannot have password in cleartext anywhere on the system?

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch I am quite sure about it because, I have been using the "jndiName" attribute to specify Database Connection credentials in my project.

Comment: @AamirQuraishi The solution you provided, though a good idea, needs an extra effort of encrypting and decrypting the passwords. But, by configuring a JNDI, you are asking the webserver to take care of this, which in turn does this for you. Its up to you to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Mavillin, good catch. Checking [the source](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_1/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/JdbcDataSource.java#L102), shows that it is indeed an option. I'll update the official Wiki to match.

Comment: Thanks Mavellin and Alexandre - will go with JNDI as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#System_property_substitution

You can keep them as properties in the file `<solr.home>/conf/solrcore.properties` and refer them in your data config. So your data-config.xml will be like:

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"    
            url="jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbc.host}:${jdbc.port}/${db.name}" 
            user="${jdbc.username}" 
            password="${jdbc.password}"/>
```

where everything in `${...}` is a property in solrcore.properties like:

```
jdbc.host=http://127.0.0.1
jdbc.port=3306
db.name=emp
...
```

Comment: Thanks Arun - but can the property file be encrypted so that SolR decrypts the property values? Our problem is that we cannot put any password in cleartext in any file anywhere.

Comment: I don't know. Try asking the solr user mailing list.