# Hashed oracle password in solr data import handler configuration

Tags: java, oracle, hash, solr, solr4

How do I create/get the existing hash for an oracle 12c user and in turn where do I add this hash into the solr dataimport handler configuration? Are there any extra config required in the solr import handler or the solr config xml to get this working?

Any help will be much appreciated. I have search on google and through various blogs but all articles refer to clear text passwords.

Comment: Would it help you to configure the datasource via JNDI as suggested in this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099776/solr-config-encrypting-data-config-file

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you very much. Can you please answer the question so that I can upvote so that I can get to 15 reputation please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the answer to [Solr config, encrypting data config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099776/solr-config-encrypting-data-config-file), you should configure your datasource via JNDI and then address it via its' JNDI name

```xml
<dataSource name="xyz" jndiName="jdbc/xyz" type="JdbcDataSource"/>
```