# SOLR 5.5.5: Encrypt Password in core.propoerties file

Tags: solr

I'm using SOLR 5.5.5. Can you please help to encrypt passwords in `core.properties` file?

Below is the data from core.properties file (file location: `../solr-5.5.5/server/solr/CS-SUDAN`)

```
#Sun Dec 09 13:42:04 AST 2018
user=SUDAN
password=SudAn#987
```

I want to encrypt password `SudAn#987`. Earlier I was using SOLR 5.3.1 and I got to know that we can't encrypt passwords in that version. Hence, we upgraded to SOLR 5.5.5.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What should this username and password be used for? What feature are you trying to use?

Comment: Do you know of the JNDI approach? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099776/solr-config-encrypting-data-config-file

Comment: In addition to Mats question, is this for the dataimport handler?

Comment: solr is new for me, it is being used in one of the SAS product. I have referred to above links suggested and solr guide. I have encrypted passwords in data-config.xml file 'openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -in pwd.txt
password="U2FsdGVkX18QMjY0yfCqlfBMvAB4d3XkwY96L7gfO2o=" 
WHen the password is encrypted, you must provide an extra attribute
encryptKeyFile="/location/of/encryptionkey". 

Thank you for your quick response.